# How to fix MS SQL linked server slowness issue for MariaDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, mariadb

I'm using SQL Link server for fetching data from  MariaDB.
But I fetching issue with slowness when i used MariaDB from link server.

I used below scenarios to fetch result (also describe time taken by query)

Please suggest if you have any solutions.

Total number of row in patient table : 62520

```
SELECT count(1) FROM [MariaDB]...[webimslt.Patient] -- 2.6 second
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MariaDB], 'select count(1) from webimslt.patient') -- 47ms
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MariaDB], 'select * from webimslt.patient') -- 20 second
```

Comment: Why are you querying Maria from sql server?

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t really a fair comparison...

`SELECT COUNT(1)` is only returning a single number and will probably be using an index to count rows.

`SELECT *` is returning ALL data from the table.

Returning data is an expensive (slow) process, so it will obviously take time to return your data. Then there is the question of data transfer, are the servers connected using a high speed connection? That is also a factor in this. It will never be as fast to query over a linked server as it is to query your database directly.

How can you improve the speed? I would start by only returning the data you need by specifying the columns and adding a where clause. After that, you can probably use indexes in Maria to try to speed things up.